# documentum Session getting error

Tags: java, documentum, dfc

```
    import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
    import com.documentum.com.IDfClientX;
    import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfClient;
    import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSession;
    import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSessionManager;
    import com.documentum.fc.client.IDfSysObject;
    import com.documentum.fc.common.IDfLoginInfo;;

    public class Samplesession {

     IDfSysObject sysObject = null;
        IDfSessionManager sessMgr = null;
        public Samplesession()
        {
         System.out.println("SessionEx constructor called!!!");
        }



       public IDfSessionManager getSessionManager(String args1, String args2, String args3) throws Exception 
        {
            IDfClientX clientx=  new DfClientX();     
           IDfClient client=clientx.getLocalClient();
           IDfSessionManager sMgr = client.newSessionManager();
           IDfLoginInfo login = clientx.getLoginInfo();
             login.setUser(args1);
                login.setPassword(args2);
                sMgr.setIdentity(args3, login);
                return sMgr;            
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      {

       String user="",password="",docbase="";
       IDfSessionManager sMgr = null;
       IDfSession session = null;
       try
       {
        Samplesession object = new Samplesession();
        sMgr=object.getSessionManager(user,password,docbase);
        session=sMgr.getSession(docbase);
        if (session != null)
         System.out.println("Session created Successfully!!!"+session);
        else
         System.out.println("Please check the login information again!!!");
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
        if (session != null)
        {
         sMgr.release(session);
         System.out.println("Session released Successfully!!!");
        }
       }
         }

 }
}
}
This is uder the dfc classes
And the errors are below!!!!!!!!

    SessionEx constructor called!!!



     0 [main] ERROR com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Problem locating log4j configuration

     0 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Using default log4j configuration

    10374 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager  - [DFC_BOF_COULDNT_CONNECT_TO_REGISTRY] Unable to connect to module registry, docbase name docbasename username dm_bof_registry.

    DfAuthenticationException:: THREAD: main; MSG: [DM_SESSION_E_AUTH_FAIL]error:  "Authentication failed for user dm_bof_registry with docbase docbasename."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseExceptionMapper.newException(DocbaseExceptionMapper.java:52)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.MessageEntry.getException(MessageEntry.java:39)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseMessageManager.getException(DocbaseMessageManager.java:137)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.checkForMessages(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:310)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForObject(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:653)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$8.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1293)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1056)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForObject(DocbaseConnection.java:1285)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.authenticateUser(DocbaseApi.java:1703)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.authenticate(DocbaseConnection.java:417)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.open(DocbaseConnection.java:128)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.<init>(DocbaseConnection.java:97)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.<init>(DocbaseConnection.java:60)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnectionFactory.newDocbaseConnection(DocbaseConnectionFactory.java:26)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnectionManager.getDocbaseConnection(DocbaseConnectionManager.java:85)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionFactory.newSession(SessionFactory.java:29)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.PrincipalAwareSessionFactory.newSession(PrincipalAwareSessionFactory.java:42)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.PooledSessionFactory.newSession(PooledSessionFactory.java:47)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.getSessionFromFactory(SessionManager.java:111)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.newSession(SessionManager.java:64)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:168)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.connect(ModuleManager.java:353)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:308)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.getInstance(ModuleManager.java:35)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.<init>(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:44)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)

     at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:191)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:734)

     at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)

     at qbe4lpg.read.sample.Samplesession.getSessionManager(Samplesession.java:22)

     at qbe4lpg.read.sample.Samplesession.main(Samplesession.java:41)

    10547 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr  - [DFC_SECURITY_GR_PUBLICATION_FAILED] Publication of DFC instance with global registry failed

    DfException:: THREAD: main; MSG: [DFC_BOF_GLOBAL_REGISTRY_UNAVAILABLE] Unable to connect to the global registry no session; ERRORCODE: ff; NEXT: null

     at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.<init>(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:55)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)

     at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:191)

     at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:734)

     at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)

     at qbe4lpg.read.sample.Samplesession.getSessionManager(Samplesession.java:22)

     at qbe4lpg.read.sample.Samplesession.main(Samplesession.java:41)

    Session created Successfully!!!com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.StrongSessionHandle@18f6559

    Session released Successfully!!!
```

I allready added config file, log4j file and added jar files also
I have done every thing but still not able to getting output

Comment: How do you start your program? What is the value of `docbase`? Is it "docbasename"? Why do you write out "Session created Successfully" when this is obviously not the case?

Comment: I added the docbase but their i mension normal name

Comment: i fixed most of them but still getting log4j Error

Comment: [main] ERROR com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Problem locating log4j configuration

     0 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Using default log4j configuration
still getting those error now

Comment: You need `log4j.properties` in your CLASSPATH to get rid of that error. If you installed DFS or DFC there should be a default log4j.properties lying around somewhere, that has some useful appenders in it. If not, try downloading it again or alternatively take a look at a log4j tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm

Btw, don't worry about the error if you don't need the logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got solution now am able to executing the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you still getting the same error message? If yes then it is because your Global Registry configuration is broken:

```
"Authentication failed for user dm_bof_registry with docbase docbasename."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
```

Check dfc.properties that should be in your CLASSPATH and look for following keys:

```
dfc.globalregistry.password=
dfc.globalregistry.repository=
dfc.globalregistry.username=dm_bof_registry
```

Make sure that the user, password and the repository (that is the docbase name) is correct - you can try logging in using those credentials using any Documentum client, e.g Documentum Administrator or Webtop to verify them.

Depending on your Content Server setup you can also try to comment out those three lines.

Comment: [main] ERROR com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Problem locating log4j configuration
0 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.common.impl.logging.LoggingConfigurator  - Using default log4j configuration

Comment: please help now am getting those error and thanks a lot that is working for me,now only above one errors am getting ,help me as soon as possible